# Zod validation does not seem to trigger for required input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zod

I have the following schema in Zod that requires a valid string input. However, I'm not sure the validation is actually kicking in? Just wondering what I'm doing wrong...

```
  const nameSchema = z.string({
    required_error: "Name is required",
    invalid_type_error: "Name must be a string",
  });  

  console.log(nameSchema.safeParse("")); //Return the following object

{
    "success": true,
    "data": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty string is also a string, that's why you are getting success.
You have to refine the empty string also to get error response for empty string as below.

```
const nameSchema = z.string({
  required_error: "Name is required",
  invalid_type_error: "Name must be a string",
}).refine(data => data.trim() !== "", {
  message: "Name cannot be an empty string",
});

console.log(nameSchema.safeParse(""));
```